# WIQL or query to get all related work-item, but NOT listing the parents

Tags: azure-devops, wiql

I have a query listing all features and their child/related work-items.

Is there a way *not* to display the features (parents) itself? Just a flat list of all work-items having a link with a feature in this project.

Comment: Is this for a dashboard count?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid you cannot use the *flat list of work items* to query the work items with links.

You can have a try using a *Work items and direct links* type of query to show the children work items of the Features on the top level. See below:

[image]

If you want to add a query result account widget on dashboards, you can check out the [Query Tile PRO](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mskold.mskold-Query-Tile-PRO) tool.

Comment: Yes, the Query Tile Pro returns the correct number of child items, at least. I can put that in a dashboard tile. Thx!